# using python2.7, how to obtain key, value items when iterating over a function that returns a dictionary in jinja2 templating

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I spent a while looking for how to do this.
I have a function that creates and returns a dictionary in python2.7 as follows

```
function():
    my_dict = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2" } #and so on
    return my_dict
```

and my templating is setup as follows:

```
 {% for key, value in function.items() %}

                    <div class="{{ key }}">
                            <a href="{{ value }}"></a>
                    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I kept getting errors "UndefinedError: 'function object' has no attribute 'items' and tried iteritems()
and when i removed items and  iteritems to have my for loop within the template as follows:

```
{% for key, value in function() %}
```

the following error is raised:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

how do i iterate properly over my function in jinja2?

Comment: What about `function().items()`?

Comment: yup, that is what i did just now

Comment: You forgot to call the function, so it returns the dictionary. Just saying `function.items()` assumes function is the dictionary, and since its a method - you get the error.

Comment: thanks burhad and niemmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, this is what worked:

```
{% for key, value in function().items() %}
                <div class="{{ key }}">
                    <a href="{{ value }}"></a>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```